# Google Gmail API Subscription Publishes Two Webhook Responses for Each New or Sent Email

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, webhooks

1. Call watch() and subscribe to inbox

```
    watch_request = Google::Apis::GmailV1::WatchRequest.new
    watch_request.topic_name = GMAIL_SUBSCRIPTION_TOPIC_NAME
    watch_response = gmail_client.service.watch_user(google_user_id, watch_request)
```

2. Send test email to that inbox or from that inbox
3. Receive two different push notifications via webhook with each having a slight different history id.  The second messages arrives a couple seconds after the first.

The gmail account seems standard.  I'm wondering if this is expected or not.  I'm beginning to think it's because `labelFilterAction` and `labelIds` are being ignored and multiple labels match a new unread email within an inbox like `UNREAD` and `INBOX`.  It's documented in other StackOverflow questions as recently as Feb 2019.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Sure, added code used to create subscription

Comment: @todd I understand it's an old question, but did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: It's okay @Alx, this was at a previous job and I don't think I did unfortunately.  I forget what we ended up doing.

Comment: totally get it! Thanks for your response though.